# Can a non-blocking Win32 system call (like ReleaseMutex) cause a thread to block and allow a lower priority thread to run?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I'm experiencing an issue where a thread is somehow being preempted by a lower-priority thread, despite the fact that the higher-priority thread doesn't make any blocking calls. I've noticed that when the lower-priority thread does preempt the higher-priority thread, the higher-priority thread is in the middle of a system call. Specifically, ReleaseMutex and Sleep(0). Is it possible that the system call is doing something that would block the current thread and allow a lower priority thread to run?

Comment: Lower-priority threads still get to run, they just get run less.

Comment: You haven't provided any code, so the explanation could be anything.   `Sleep()` does cause a thread to relinquish its time slice, which allows other threads to run even if they are of lower priority.     I wouldn't necessarily bet your code is blocking on `ReleaseMutex()` - more likely, it is completing some action, doing something (e.g. calling `Sleep()`) that relinquishes its timeslice, or waiting on something) and then making the call of `ReleaseMutex()` that you are seeing.   Or the scheme you are using to detect these system calls (e.g. your debugger) is simply imprecise.

Comment: And keep in mind that nearly all systems are now multi-core. Even if you have a higher priority thread that simply runs a busy loop (while(1) {}) your lower priority threads will still get a chance to run on any other core.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir good point. I forgot to mention that I set the process affinity mask to one core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Priority just means that there is some amount of preference for one thread over another. It can always be the case that a thread can't make forward progress for some reason and a lower-priority thread then pre-empts it.

Imagine, for example, if `ReleaseMutex` happens to wind up in some rare code path due to some strange edge case and the code for handling that edge case has paged out to disk. The thread that called `ReleaseMutex` is not ready-to-run until that code pages in, so a lower-priority thread can get the CPU.

I don't think that's a particularly likely scenario. But the point is that it's not guaranteed not to happen. Priority is not an exclusionary method or a synchronization mechanism. It's just a way of indicating what you prefer when the system happens to have a choice.

If this is causing you an issue, you have something very wrong in your design. If you're trying to use thread priorities as a way of guaranteeing particular behavior (rather than indicating preferences) you are handling exclusion entirely wrong.

Comment: Okay. I am used to working in RTOS and didn't realized general purpose OSes differed in this way. Thanks.

Comment: Here is another reason for a lower-priority thread to preempt and higher-priority thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/priority-inversion.

Comment: If you have all the threads restricted to one core, then AFAIK, the only time a thread will preempt a higher-priority thread is if the thread has been starved for around 5 seconds (on my machine it's 5 seconds anyways). At this point, Win32's priority inversion kicks in. I also read it here: https://www.itprotoday.com/compute-engines/inside-windows-nt-scheduler-part-1 and tested it myself.